# How to get region/province code from IP address

Tags: highcharts, geolocation, ip, ip-address

IP-Geo-Locator usually give information about country, country code, region, lat & long, etc. But in some case i must define the region code (that was not served by IP-Geo-Locator in usual) in highchart (like US-AL, US-CA, US-FL).

How to get that region code by ip address ? 
or should i define that region code manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ISO 3166-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) is part of the ISO 3166 standard published by the International Organization for Standardization (ISO) for identifying the principal subdivisions (e.g., provinces or states) of all countries.

[IP2Location](https://www.ip2location.com) is the only IP geolocation database provider I aware that it is fully compliance with this ISO 3166 standard. They also provide [free subdivision](https://www.ip2location.com/free/iso3166-2) database in their web site.

I hope I have answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ipinfodb.com/

will return Area Code. once you get the Area Code then you must be able to get the region code.